# How to manage AWS tokens in Flask and handle refreshes

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-batch

**Use case and problem:**

I am running a Flask application that connects to a specific AWS service. The language I am using is Python3 and the library is boto3.

My services are working as intended but there is an issue; with the secret access tokens and such, these expire after N amount of time - for running this application on a live server this is a problem for obvious reasons like the users could only use the app for 15 mins or whenever the token is set to expire and then we're presented with the problem.. How do I retrieve the token again without manual intervention?

**Specific question**:

What service, library, or configuration is needed to accomplish this task? All answers I have looked at seem to assume this application is a script or running locally on the developer system which doesn't work for me as I need to deploy this onto a live server and have logic in place to know when the token is expired and then fetch a new token and so on.. for the duration of the runtime for the application

I didn't include any code here because this is more of a DevOps question I think or close to but also I think it's better to keep the boto3 code I have out of the question in order to not contaminate my question with distractions.

Comment: Where do you run your python? EC2 instance?

Comment: @Marcin yes for prod